# r can't read dput output back in

Tags: r, flextable

The code and associated dput output generate a table header that has two rows. The top row has the original column names. the second row is the new column names. I'd like to display only the second row. How can I turn off/hide the first row?

```
library(flextable)
library(stringr)
d <- structure(list(ISO3 = c("AFG", "AGO", "ALB", "AND", "ARE", "ARG", "ARM", "AUS", "AUT", "AZE"), Name = c("Afghanistan", "Angola", "Albania", "Andorra", "United Arab Emirates", "Argentina", "Armenia", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan"), `annual_historical_1991-2010` = c(96, 84, 96, 98, 77, 93, 97, 88, 98, 94), `annual_ssp126_2041-2060` = c(94, 80, 94, 97, 71, 92, 96, 85, 97, 92), `annual_ssp126_2081-2100` = c(94, 80, 94, 97, 72, 92, 96, 85, 97, 91), `annual_ssp585_2041-2060` = c(93, 78, 93, 96, 69, 91, 95, 83, 97, 91), `annual_ssp585_2081-2100` = c(89, 69, 88, 93, 57, 87, 91, 77, 94, 85), `hot90_historical_1991-2010` = c(89, 76, 88, 94, 58, 87, 91, 76, 95, 83), `hot90_ssp126_2041-2060` = c(85, 71, 82, 90, 50, 84, 86, 72, 92, 77), `hot90_ssp126_2081-2100` = c(85, 71, 82, 90, 50, 84, 86, 72, 92, 76), `hot90_ssp585_2041-2060` = c(83, 68, 79, 88, 46, 82, 84, 70, 90, 74), `hot90_ssp585_2081-2100` = c(73, 56, 67, 79, 31, 75, 73, 59, 83, 60), `season_historical_1991-2010` = c(96, 84, 95, 98, 76, 93, 97, 92, 98, 93), `season_ssp126_2041-2060` = c(94, 81, 92, 96, 71, 91, 95, 90, 97, 91), `season_ssp126_2081-2100` = c(94, 80, 92, 96, 72, 91, 95, 90, 97, 90), `season_ssp585_2041-2060` = c(93, 78, 91, 95, 69, 90, 94, 89, 96, 89), `season_ssp585_2081-2100` = c(88, 69, 85, 91, 58, 86, 90, 84, 93, 84)), row.names = c(2L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 14L, 15L, 16L), class = "data.frame")

col_labels <- str_replace(names(d), "_ssp126_", " SSP1-2.6, ") |> 
  str_replace("_ssp585_", " SP5-8.5, ") |>
  str_replace("_historical_", " Historical, ") |>
  str_replace("annual ", "") |> 
  str_replace("hot90 ", "") |> 
  str_replace("season ", "")

names_list <-  as.list(setNames(col_labels, names(d)))

t_flex <- as_flextable(d)  |>
  set_header_labels(values = names_list)
t_flex
```

Comment: Try `flextable(d) |> set_header_labels(values = names_list)`. `as_flextable` will give you a two row header with the column names and the data types. And as it looks, when you use `set_header_labels` the row with the data types is replaced by your labels.

Comment: `d |> setNames(col_labels) |> as_flextable()` maybe ? I don't understand what this question has to do with `dput`

Comment: re dput, the answer is nothing. I originally had a problem with reading back in the dput output but solved it and forgot to remove dput from the topic list.

Comment: @stefan, make that an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the docs (`?as_flextable.data.frame`):

> It displays the first rows and shows the column types.

Also, `set_header_labels`

> set(s) labels for specified columns in the bottom row header of a flextable.

Hence, the issue is that `as_flextable` will give you a table with a two row header where the second or bottom row contains the datatypes which are then replaced by you labels via `set_header_labels`.

Instead you could use `flextable()`:

```
library(flextable)

flextable(d) |>
  set_header_labels(values = names_list)
```

[image]